# Adding div from JSON in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, dom

I am getting some data from a page in JSON format
JSON:
         {
           'name' : 'maverick',
           Image : 'Jason'
         }

I now need to take these values and add them to the #main div.

```
        <div id="main">
        <div class="a"> name: Eithan <img src="img/Eithan.jpg" /> <div>
        <div class="a"> name: Emma <img src="img/Emma.jpg" /> <div>
       </div>
```

How do I do that in jQuery for the case there are several objects in the JSON?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using `$.getJSON()` function.

```
$.getJSON("link/to/json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#main').append('<div class="a"> name: ' + item.name + ' <img src="img/' + item.image + '.jpg" /></div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Ted, If you loading json from another domain then you will be restricted by cross domain policy, on that you have to use `jsonp` request.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the JSON and append a div:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('#main').append('<div class="a"> name: ' + item.name + ' <img src="img/' + item.image + '.jpg" /></div>');
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if you put the JSON in an array, like so (which works for multiple items)

```
[
    {'name':'maverick', 'image':'Jason'},
    {'name':'Darlig', 'image':'Rose'}
]
```

(note wrapping everything in `[` and `]` which signifies JSON array)

Now you can just use a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var currentPerson = response[i];
    var currentName = currentPerson.name;
    var currentImage = currentPerson.image;

    //use currentName and currentImage to add to the DOM
}
```